# Kantorovich-Rubinstein theorem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-transport

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments.

---

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Let $\mathcal P(X), \mathcal P(Y)$ be the spaces of all Borel probability measures on $X,Y$ respectively. Let $c: X \times Y \to [0, +\infty]$. Fix $\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$.

- $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is the set of $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ such that for all measurable subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$,
  $$
  \pi (A \times Y) = \mu (A) \quad \text{and} \quad \pi (X \times B) = \nu (B).
  $$
- $\Phi_{c}$ is the set of all $(\varphi, \psi) \in L_1 (\mu) \times L_1 (\nu)$ satisfying
  $$
  \varphi(x)+\psi(y) \leq c(x, y)
  $$
  for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$.
- For $\pi \in \mathcal P(X \times Y)$ and $(\varphi, \psi) \in L_1 (\mu) \times L_1 (\nu)$, let
  $$
  \mathbb K (\pi) := \int_{X \times Y} c d \pi \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi) := \int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu .
  $$

> **Kantorovich-Rubinstein:** Let $X = Y$ be Polish spaces and and $c$ a lower semi-continuous metric. Define
> $$
> \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} = \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{c(x, y)}.
> $$
> Assume that there exists $(a,a) \in X \times Y$ such that $c( \cdot, a) \in L_1(\mu)$ and  $c(a, \cdot) \in L_1(\nu)$. Then
> $$
> \min_{\pi \in \Pi (\mu, \nu)} \mathbb K (\pi) = \sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1 \right \}.
> $$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. $c$ is bounded, i.e., $\sup_{x, y\in X} c(x, y) < C$ for some $C \in \mathbb R$.

Then $\|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1$ implies $f$ is bounded, and thus $f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|)$ and $(-f, f) \in \Phi_{c}$. By [Kantorovich duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449059/a-proof-of-kantorovich-duality?noredirect=1&lq=1), it suffices to prove
$$
\sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi) = \sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1 \right \}.
$$

If $f \in L_1 (\mu)$, then
$$
f^c:Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}, y \mapsto \inf_{x \in X} [c(x, y) - f(x)]
$$
is such that $\|f^c\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1$ and $f^{cc} = -f^c$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453197/is-this-shorter-attempt-on-the-existence-of-the-maximizer-in-kantorovich-duality?noredirect=1&lq=1) lemma, we have
$$
\sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi) = \sup _{f \in L_1 (\mu)} \mathbb J(f^{cc}, f^c) = \sup _{f \in L_1 (\mu)} \mathbb J(-f^{c}, f^c)  \le \sup _{\|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1} \mathbb J(-f, f)  \le \sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi).
$$

> 2. $c$ is unbounded.

We have
$$
\sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1 \right \} \le \sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi).
$$

It remains to prove
$$
\sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1 \right \} \ge \sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi).
$$

Let $c_n := \min\{n, c\}$. Then $c$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813166/368425) a bounded metric on $X$ such that $c_n \nearrow c$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452551/if-c-n-nearrow-c-then-lim-n-inf-pi-in-pi-mu-nu-int-c-n-d-pi-i) result, we have
$$
\lim_n \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c_n d\pi = \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d\pi = \sup _{\Phi_{c}} \mathbb J(\varphi, \psi).
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
\inf_{\pi \in \Pi (\mu, \nu)} \int_{X \times Y} c_n d \pi &= \sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}, c_n} \le 1 \right \} \\
&\le \sup \left \{ \int_X f d (\mu - \nu) \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu- \nu|) , \|f\|_{\mathrm{Lib}} \le 1 \right \}.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.