# Reference Request: Dense Set + Compactly Supported Functions in Uniform Topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a dense subset of $C(\mathbb{R})$ for the [compact-convergence topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence) such that each $f \in X$ has non-compact support, for each $f \in X$ let
$$
C_f :=\left\{
g \in C(\mathbb{R}):(\exists h \in C_0(\mathbb{R}))\, g=f+h 
\right\},
$$
and equip $C(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology generated by the [(possibly infinite metric)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399722/metric-assuming-the-value-infinity)
$$
d(f,g) := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} \|f(x)-g(x)\|
.
$$

Has the space $X+C_0$ in the latter topology ever been considered?  If so is it and what would some references be?

Comment: Well, replacing $X$ with its closure under compact convergence just replaces the assumption that "$X$ is a subset and no $f\in X$ has compact support" to "$X$ is a subspace and some $f\in X$ has non-compact support", and then it's harmless to assume that $C_0\subset X$ (changing $X$ to $X+C_0$). The topology on $C(R)$ you're considering is just a disjoint union of cosets of the subspace $C_b(X)$ of bounded functions, and $X+C_0$ lies as some subset of this one in some way which I'm not sure there is a lot interesting to say.

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering if any function in $C(\mathbb{R})$ can be approximated uniformly by first approximating most of it on a large compact and then approximating the "extra part" separately.... somehow..

Comment: This seems to be essentially hopeless. Compact convergence is way too weak. For instance you have plenty of countable $X$ that satisfy your compact convergence density assumption, while $C(R)$ is not separable (since it has the uncountable discrete quotient $C(R)/C_b(R)$).

Comment: So essentially, you're saying we need the set of orbits $X/C_b(R)$ to be dense in $C(R)/C_b(R)$?  Then we'd have our result...  But what is $C(R)/C_b(R)$ (besides its abstract definition...)

Comment: This quotient is discrete. I'm just saying that if $Y\subset C(R)$ is dense for the topology of uniform convergence, then the projection of $Y$ in the (huge) quotient space $C(R)/C_b(R)$ is the whose set. And also $Y\cap C_b(R)$ has to be dense in $C_b(R)$, and already $C_b(R)$ is a non-separable Banach space.