# Metric space dilemma

Tags: metric-spaces

Can we define a metric $d$ on any set $X$ s.t. $d(x, y)=\infty$ $\forall x, y$, $x\neq y$

In this case, how will X look like?
And What will be the open sets of $X$.

Maybe definition allows only real value of $d$.
What will be the consequences of defining $d$ in this way?

Comment: A condition of a metric is that its finite. Another is that it is zero if $x=y$.

Comment: yeah! So is that any space! where this all is possible? Have anybody ever defined it so?

Comment: What you have defined is not a metric.  Questions like what are the open sets aren't really valid here. Imagine if the 'distance' between $0$ and $0$ was infinite. What does that even mean?

Comment: Have a look at [extended metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Extended_metrics)

Comment: I think even extended metrics require $d(x,x)=0$.

Comment: @tomasliam I should have said for distinct x and y.. then...?

Comment: In that case it would kind of be an extension to the discrete metric. As for what properties it has, I am not sure. But I doubt it would be anything meaningfully different.

Comment: @tomasliam yeah... thank you. I was just wondering if anybody has come across this kind of space.

Comment: Provided that one should have $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$ because... well, that obviously makes sense, there is an interesting (perhaps over-enthousiastic) answer by Ittay Weiss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399722/metric-assuming-the-value-infinity). See also the discussion in the comments with former user hmakholmleftoverMonica over some nuances, mainly the fact that $[0,\infty]$ with the obvious extended metric is homeomorphic to $[0,1)\cup \{2\}$, and not to $[0,1]$ as the inattentive reader might think.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you. I will have a look, seems interesting.