# Existence of a continuous function in this case

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself and define the following metric on $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ : $d(f,g) = sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)-g(x)|$

Is there a continuous function from the interval $[0,1]$ to $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $0$ is mapped to $f(x) = x$ and $1$ is mapped to $g(x) = -x$?

My first guess was to take the function that maps each $a \in [0,1]$ to the function $(1-2a)x$ but I don't think this map would be continuous because if you take any two distinct $a,b \in [0,1]$, we have that $d((1-2a)x,(1-2b)x)$ is infinitely large, so I don't think this map could be continuous. This makes me think that there is no continuous function as above actually, because the distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ themselves is infinitely large.

Is this right? If so, how would you write a formal proof of this? If not, then what is the continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ that maps $0$ to $x$ and $1$ to $-x$?

Comment: $d$ is not a metric since it can take the value $\infty$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I did notice that and asked my lecturer about it. I think the idea is to really just "ignore" when the distance is infinity.

Comment: You can't just "ignore" the core issue with your "metric". Since the metric is not well defined, then continuity is not well defined as well. This whole question is invalid.

Comment: Are you sure? The question is in my Lecture notes for my topology course at University and this topology on the set $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is used a few times.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. What makes sense is to talk about compact-open topology on $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. In that case continuous paths are the same as classical homotopies. In other words you have to show that if $H:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homotopy such that $H(0,x)=x$ and $H(1,x)=-x$ then there is $t$ such that $H(t,\cdot)$ is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: There is no problem with $\infty$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399722.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is a bit unusual to consider a "metric" which is allowed to take the value $\infty$, but we can work with a more general definition  of "metric" as discussed in [Metric assuming the value infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399722).

This approach via the generalized metric $d$ gives us a topology on $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, it is easy to verify that the same topology is induced by the ordinary metric $d_1(f,g) = \min (1,d(f,g))$.

Assume that there exists a continuous map $u : I = [0,1] \to Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that $u(0) = id$ and $u(1) = -id$. Since $I$ is compact, $u$ is uniformly continuous and therefore we can find $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $d(u(t),u(s)) \le 1$ for $\lvert t  - s \rvert \le 1/n$. This shows that
$$d(u(0),u(1)) \le  \sum_{i=1}^n d\left(u\left(\frac{i-1}{n}\right), u\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)\right) \le n .$$
But clearly $d(id,-id) = \infty$, a contradiction.

A perhaps more natural way to topologize $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is to use the compact open topology (see freakish's comment). But let us take yet another topology on $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ : The topology of *pointwise convergence*. A subbasis for this topology is given by the sets $M(x,U) = \{ f \in Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \mid f(x) \in U \}$, where $x \in \mathbb R$  and $U \subset \mathbb R$ is open. This topology is coarser then your metric topology and coarser than the compact-open topology. We shall show that there exists no continuous path from $id$ to $-id$ with respect to the topology of pointwise convergence, which is a much stronger result than that proved above.

Let us define
$$H_+ = \{f \in Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \mid f(1) > f(0) \} , \\
H_- = \{f \in Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \mid f(1) < f(0) \} .$$

These sets form a partition of $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ into disjoint subsets.

The set $H_+$ is open: Let $f \in H_+$ which means $f(1) > f(0)$. Let $r = (f(1) - f(0))/2$. Then $f \in W = S(1, (f(1) - r,\infty)) \cap S(0, (-\infty, f(0) + r))$. The set $W$ is open in $Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ . For $g \in W$ we have $g(1) \in  (f(1) - r,\infty)$ and $g(0) \in (-\infty, f(0) + r)$. This implies $g(1) > g(0)$, i.e. $g  \in H_+$. Thus $f \in W \subset H_+$.

Similarly $H_-$ is open.

Now let $u : I \to Top^h(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous path. The sets $I_\pm = u^{-1}(H_\pm)$ form a partition of $I$ into disjoint open subsets. Since $I$ is connected, one of $I_\pm$ must be empty and the other $= I$.

This shows that there is no continuous path connecting an element of $H_+$ with an element of $H_-$. But $id  \in H_+$ and $-id \in H_-$.